# Low current, long life batteries with an extended temperature range?

Tags: batteries

I'm working on a product with a specified -40 to 85 degC temperature range, and I'd like to have a RTC with a coin cell or similar battery backup.

Beyond that temperature range, damage to the battery is acceptable... as long as it doesn't explode under 125 degC.

I also believe that my initial client's industry has an aversion to the word "lithium", so lithium-anything is potentially problematic.  (Unless I can point to something very authoritative saying it's perfectly safe and that it adds no hassles in shipping requirements)

It doesn't need to be rechargeable, really. It'd be a bonus, but not a requirement.

What reasonably attainable battery fits these criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to do some searching to find exactly what you want, but it's out there.  For example, here's a link to some Panasonic batteries that work from -40 to +125 deg C:  http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/batteries-oem/oem/primary-coin-cylindrical/high-operating-temperature.aspx

That web page doesn't say it's lithium, but odds are that it is.  That might be one thing that your client will just have to deal with.  Lithium is no less reliable than other chemistries.  That being said, there are other battery chemistries like Silver Oxide, Zinc Air, and Alkaline Manganese that might work for you-- but a quick search of the Duracell web site didn't return any temperature data for those.

The other option is to do some out of the box thinking.  Maybe a small solar cell plus supercap.

Comment: Those look nice, although Digikey's MSDS link for that chemistry takes you to a document that refers to a requirement for a big label saying "PRIMARY LITHIUM BATTERIES - FORBIDDEN FOR TRANSPORT ABOARD PASSENGER AIRCRAFT". There's a note that it CAN be shipped by air according to various listed standards as of Jan 2011, but it doesn't specify that that includes passenger aircraft. I'd guess not, since the labeling requirement is still apparently valid. It also strangely says not to heat over 100 degC (which is really odd for a -40 to 125 degC rated battery)

Comment: I've searched a bit at this point... I'm not finding much temperature data for Silver Oxide, etc either. I was hoping someone on here had already solved this problem. :)

Comment: I borrowed a very large book on batteries "Handbook of Batteries 3rd edition" which is nearly 10 years old but seems to do a good job of showing me what I'm up against. It doesn't look good... one chart lists quite a few different battery chemistries including operating temperature, and nothing is really coming close. I may need to just make the battery a build option. I'd hate to have the units lose the clock just in transport, though. Perhaps I'll make some extra pins on an external connector for a special external battery module for transport. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of battery capacity and RTC duration do you need?  If your duration is short enough, a super-capacitor might be the better way to go.

That said, double check the regulations on lithium batteries.  The rules keep changing around - I don't know the exact state of things today, as I haven't looked at making a new RTC circuit in a few years - but many batteries are sufficiently low-energy that they are allowed for air shipment.

Coin batteries, IIRC, are ok. I believe your first step is to e-mail your battery supplier (in my case, it was Panasonic, via Digikey) to ask for their latest document on safety and transportability.

Answer (score 0):

Super capacitors will not work because the electrolyte will freeze. Perhaps newer versions don't have this problem. But I haven't seen anything like that yet. The only option is a lithium based battery.